# hadoop installation -hadooop-home set error

Tags: hadoop, path, hdfs

I'm installing  Hanborq optimized Hadoop Distribution (fully distribution mode ) ,i followed all steps exactly  in the following links,and there is no errors happened .when I reach to step that format the hdfs file :

$ hadoop namenode -format

An error accursed tells that "HADOOP_HOME is not set correctly 
please set your hadoop_home variable to the absolute path of the directorythat contains hadoop-core-VERSION.jar"

[installation_steps_1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm)
[installation_steps_2](http://letshadoopit.com/installing-apache-hadoop-in-fully-distributed-mode/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not set HADOOP_HOME correctly in .bashrc file. Add below lines in your .bashrc file and execute it by `. .bashrc`. Please give reply if it works

`#HADOOP_HOME setup
export HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6"
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH`

Note: HADOOP_HOME is location of hadoop directory